# How to add code snippets to VSIX MEF editor extension without language service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mef, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to implement code snippets with a MEF editor extension with VS2012, I followed the walkthrough "Implementing Code Snippets" from the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926100(v=vs.110).aspx

The implementation is based on the walkthrough Displaying Statement Completion. This feature works fine.

The first section of "Implementing Code Snippets" is "Creating and Registering Code Snippets" which does not work. At the end of the section is the step 8:

*Build and run the project. In the experimental instance of Visual Studio that starts when the project is run, the snippet you just registered should be displayed in the Code Snippets Manager under the TestSnippets language.*

There are no errors, but the Code Snippets Manager does not display the TestSnippets language, and as a consequence the snippets are not there. I have been stuck for a few weeks now with this, and could not find resources to understand the issue.

Any idea on how to solve this issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's not that easy, but I've been messing with VSIX for quite a while now. If you want to fix such problems, you need to do hardcore debugging, using reflector or dotPeek.

By debugging, I mean, you need to debug line by line the code of the actual implementation of all the MEF plumbing, and what uses MEF.

Basically, just find out where the "Code Snippets Manager" is doing its work, then see why your language is not pulled in.

Basically, you need to ask a question:

1) Why doesn't Code Snippets Manager display TestSnippets language?

And then, you just need to answer it by debugging, find where the Code Snippets Manager does the decision of displaying languages, and see why it doesn't appear there.

I've fixed quite a lot of problems this way, and I am grateful that most of the code is C#, which means it's easy to step through code and see where the execution is going.

Comment: The Code Snippets Manager is part of the Visual Studio code, How do you debug VS code?

Comment: @MiguelV; just download reflector(google it), that allows you to step into any code. Just put breakpoint to your code, and once VisualStudio calls it, you can navigate backwards through call stack and put breakpoints to VS code.